# Support for Calendar/ HashMap/ HashSet in RealmObject/RealmModel

Tags: android, realm

My RealmObject/RealmModel consists of Calendar/ HashMap/ HashSet. I know that Realm does not support these, but is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Convert them into values that realm does support, convert them back when you need them. E.g. store calendar days, hours, minutes in longs etc

Comment: Can you provide an example explaining a proper way to do this

Comment: No, it depends on what data you have and what you want to store

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Calendar`, use `Date` from `calendar.getTime()`

For `HashSet`, use `RealmList`

For `HashMap`, you need a field for the Key inside your object, and then you get the item back using `realm.where(Value.class).equalTo("keyField", key).findAll()`.